# What gets kills with deployed turrets?

Tags: planetside-2

With the new update to planetside 2, we now have structure building. Very cool!

You can build turrets, and you can build modules that automate the turrets.
If the auto turrets kill something, it counts as a kill for you.

Question is, what deployable is actually counting for the kill? Say I deploy a turret, and a friendly deploys a module. Who would get the kill in that scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The turret/turret builder gets the kill, not the module/module builder. Though if someone else is in your turret, they get the kill instead of you. IMO the dev's should add assists to both cases.